# How to generate React components dynamically using an array of Props in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I've been tackling an issue of abstracting out some logic for component creation in order to reduce a lot of duplication. As part of this, I have a generic `Builder` component which I use to dynamically render components baased on the props provided.

The issue comes from the fact that I defined elements as similar to the following:

```
type InputMap = typeof INPUTS
const INPUTS = {
  text: {
    component: TextInput,
    controlled: false
  },
  select: {
    component: Select
    controlled: true
  }
}

// Props for TextInput component
type TextProps = {
  onChange: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
  onBlur: (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void
}

// Props for Select component
type ElementProps = {
  onChange: (value: string) => void
  onBlur: () => void
}
```

I want to pass on my fields in a format similar to this:

```
const fields = [
  {
    input: "text",
    props: {
      onChange: e => console.log(e.target.value)

    }
  },
  {
    input: "select",
    props: {
      onChange: value => console.log(value)
    }
  }
]
```

This is the type I came up with:

```
import { ComponentProps } from "react";

export type FieldConfig<T extends FieldValues, K extends keyof InputMap> = {
  input: K;
  props?: ComponentProps<InputMap[K]["Component"]>
};
```

However in my `Builder` component, there's an issue when rendering the component.

```
<div>
  { fields.map(({ input, props }) => {
    const { Component, controlled } = INPUTS[input]
    return <Component {...props} /> // ERROR HERE
  })}
</div>
const { input, props } = field
```

TypeScript at that point gives me the following error:

```
Types of property 'onBlur' are incompatible.
Type 'ChangeHandler' is not assignable to type '() => void'
```

Is there any way for me to narrow the types from a union to a specific instance of that union in this case? I'm trying my best to avoid any type assertions here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a common field interface and a union type to define how your form structure should be handled like this.

```
interface FieldDefinition<TType extends string, TElement extends HTMLElement> {
    input: TType
    placeholder?: string
    onChange?: React.ChangeEventHandler<TElement>
    onBlur?: React.ChangeEventHandler<TElement>
}

interface TextField extends FieldDefinition<'text', HTMLInputElement> {
}

interface SelectField extends FieldDefinition<'select', HTMLSelectElement> {
    options: Record<PropertyKey, any>
}

type FormField = TextField | SelectField

const formFields: FormField[] = [
    {
        input: 'text',
        onChange: (event) => console.log(event.target.value)
    },
    {
        input: 'select',
        onChange: (event) => console.log(event.target.value),
        options: {
            foo: 'Foo',
            bar: 'Bar',
            baz: 'Baz'
        }
    }
]
```

This allows it to be properly used when returning the JSX, [here's a link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=33&ssc=2&pln=3&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wChTgA7GJKTdJOAMWCQBsATAESUyuBjAIlADwAVMQE8wjJAA8alDgGc4ymFCoBzADRwxAUTZIQSanHmKVcABJiAsgBkjJszAB8cAN6k4fuFRgAK4wAFz6UjK%20-mBsDAAWEJy0APzh6pqUWtF%20wgDC8ShZSGmIxDAAdAVFWkgGAG5uNkUcxlDiLqbU7jlwwgBCbEFQpcjoldXFDU0tbR3GXR6kAL7kVDR0DPqWLOwcFgpm1rucPHyUAkKi%20DQK%20Hp2TgCSlMEwnW6ePqsU1LT0aEYAGV2EgMCd9pYjqoIWd%20IJhCJ8MpQSQHg5HCDjBgPt1vL0IGAEZRlOFkGhoBwRAAFHAyWCSADSSEkeiKkh6Pxg0kYTGgIAhcAAvNsFIKAD5wLFgmAQ8gUklYfkQ0nMZWsTgAbQAusK4Jrej5-MaAq8QuEbpZ7r1jflCsVwgAKJCNagASmFngVyiSSAqbAgWmdrsqMBQUFqlXqKCGSDdvWWOkNNv8gXNBBR2Jg1pN-jtNSQTpdbg9Qq9wh9xn9geDbgqYYjSCjMaCcaTudyRKuqqNHeNmAgEAtfIgOb7-gARuGLf1w2Px3ApwAvGcoJdkPurY2rbXyivwIG4JB5XCQShuPWO0tfXpEGDDShwR0pvwiDjAeo9Bd%20LwDqACjUVAqEAUDAR1HT4PY9CoDh5GvfFvxNZQAHcBDQeIn0gzgKjTGAPV7RDczQFAUQIW5s3CAjCL7b14C8U03j0CpmLAOlVGWPUsI4F9qP8O8HzgERcO8ZiKlYwllA4gB6L9eO3cg5ONYjSORVEKIQxSiP3bwGJCPRCWJZQmJYti4A4kUuJ4uT%20KgR9n00hcREzGURJMiTllkhzvy8AB5CcACsZQqaNY2UR0DO7N1gNA8DNRC1s9DiCd2G1eCRAi4Q4AAaxZIUvHipAOIKvKCo8rwkvYZYRCkjLKHcN0ty8jtqucjBPKa%20MvMa6juvHZYGp46r30-Xp41WIA) to a TypeScript playground showing it used as a component.

This has the added bonus of allowing you to define specific type specific properties that can be defined like an `options` object for the `select` input.

Comment: I think this ties back into my original approach but I still run into where this assumes a common data signature for the onChange and onBlur (and other shared props) between the components. I may I'll keep looking around for a bit more of a flexible solution but I really appreciate the answer! I'll mark as the solution if nothing else comes up.